# Regular expression not working with Apex class while working in JS

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I have a regular expression: `\d+|[a-z]+`. What this does is, if you have 81a, it splits into 81 and a. I have tested it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it works fine. I use it in my JavaScript code using match and works fine there too.

The problem is I need use this in my apex class, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I used both

```
String numberAddress = '818a';
Boolean test = Pattern.matches('/\\d+|[a-z]+/ig', numberAddress);
List<String> splitted = numberAddress.split('/\\d+|[a-z]+/ig');
```

On doing system debug I get `test` as `false` and `splitted` as a list with one element `818a` and not `(818, a)`.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: The forward slashes in regular expression syntax for Javascript are not actually part of the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use case of splitting letters and numbers into separate groups is a good match for [`String.splitByCharacterType()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_splitByCharacterType), which splits a string into groups of contiguous characters of a single character type (as defined by Java's `Character.getType()`).

```
String numberAddress = '818a';
List<String> splitted = numberAddress.splitByCharacterType();
System.debug('splitted: ' + JSON.serialize(splitted));
```

This will output:

```
07:45:28.160 (161909627)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|splitted: ["818","a"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Split isn't the same as match. If you split, you're going to get no output, because the parameter is a boundary match. To get the results you expect, use a Matcher:

```
String numberAddress = '818a';
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(\\d+)|([a-zA-Z]+)');
Matcher m = p.matcher(numberAddress);
while(m.find()) {
    system.debug(m.group(0));
}
```

Note also that the `/.../ig` form of RegExp only works in JavaScript, Perl, and a few other languages. For Apex, you can use the inline flag set instead:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(?i)(\\d+)|([a-z]+)');
```

The `g` flag is unnecessary for a Matcher, as it will iterate through each successful match when you use `find()`.